# What is the smallest variety of algebras containing all fields?

Tags: semigroups, universal-algebra

A field is a ring whose nonzero elements form a commutative group under multiplication. A field is also a commutative [inverse semigroup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_semigroup) with respect to multiplication. The unique multiplicative inverse $y$ of an element $x$ (in the sense that $xyx=x$ and $yxy=y$) is $y=x^{-1}$ if $x \neq 0$ and $y=0$ if $x = 0$.

To simplify the discussion, define an *inverse ring* to be a ring which is an inverse semigroup with respect to multiplication. Denote the multiplicative inverse operation by $()^{-1}$. (Warning: The notion of an *inverse ring* doesn't exist outside of this question.) Both rings and *inverse rings* form a [variety of algebras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variety_%28universal_algebra%29), i.e. they can be defined by a set of operations ($+$, $*$, $-()$, $()^{-1}$, $0$, $1$ in this case) together with set of identities satisfied by these operations. I think that the commutative *inverse rings* are the smallest variety of algebras containing all fields.

**Question**

> A direct product of a family of fields is no longer a field. However, it is still a commutative *inverse ring*. My question is whether every commutative *inverse ring* is a [subdirect product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdirect_product) of a family of fields.

(Note that *subdirect product* here must refer to either rings or *inverse rings*, because the notion of *subalgebra* isn't defined otherwise. The answer to my question should be independent of which one we choose, but referring to *inverse rings* would make more sense to me.)

**Edit** The original question wasn't restricted to fields, and asked how to prove $HSP(K)=ISP(K)$. The current question asks whether $HSP(K)=P_S(K)$ for the class $K$ of fields (interpreted as algebras by extending the multiplicative inverse operation to a global operation). Because the original question didn't received any feedback, I decided to narrow down the question and ask about a stronger statement ($HSP(K)=P_S(K)$ implies $HSP(K)=ISP(K)$) without explicitly asking about a proof.

Comment: Reposted as http://mathoverflow.net/questions/91889/what-is-the-smallest-variety-of-algebras-containing-all-fields at mathoverflow. The question has been answered there with 'yes', including a short proof...

Comment: Are you sure that inverse rings form a variety of algebras? The definition appears to include the assertion that inverses are *unique*, which isn't (obviously) described by an identity.

Comment: @Hurkyl Good observation that this a non-trivial (even so well known) fact. I tend to verify at [mathematical structures](http://math.chapman.edu/~jipsen/structures/doku.php/inverse_semigroups) whether I got such properties right. There is written "Classtype: variety" and the important identity (ensuring uniqueness) is "idempotents commute: $xx^{-1}y^{-1}y=y^{-1}yxx^{-1}$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following answer is based on the answer from Simon Henry at MO (to have an accepted answer, and to check again whether I still understand the proof).

The first step is to take an arbitrary commutative *inverse ring* $A$, let $M(A)$ be the set of maximal ideals of $A$ and look at the map
$$A \rightarrow \prod_{\rho\in M(A)}A/\rho $$
Each projection is surjective, all $A/\rho$ are fields, so we just need to check that this map is injective.

This construction with the maximal ideals is precisely what I was looking for when I wrote: "I wonder whether there isn't a much simpler proof, somehow related to the fact that the subalgebras of the algebras in K have only trivial congruences." in my initial question.

In order to check whether this map is injective, we have to show that its kernel is $\{0\}$. The kernel is the intersection of all maximal ideals of $A$, which is one of the characterizations of the Jacobson radical $J(A)$. Let $x\in J(A)$ then $(1−xy)$ is invertible for all $y$, because [it can be shown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobson_radical) that "$x$ is in $J(A)$ if and only if $yx$ is left [quasiregular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiregular_element) for all $y$ in $A$." For $y=x^{-1}$ we have $y(1-xy)=y-x^{-1}xx^{-1}=y-x^{-1}=0$ so that we can conclude $y=0$. But $x=y^{-1}=0^{-1}=0$ and hence $J(A)=\{0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't know enough category theory to be certain if there is a well-defined notion of "smallest" for varieties, it is clear that any class containing all fields is a proper class; Löwenheim-Skolem in ZFC verifies that for any cardinality $ \kappa $ there exists a field $ F $ with $ card(F)=\kappa $.

It is even possible to show directly (but in a set-theoretically less well defined way) that there are fields with arbitrary cardinality: Given an arbitrary integral domain $ R $, consider $ R[\kappa] $, the ring of (finite) polynomials in $ \kappa $ variables is also an integral domain, and thus it can be made into the fraction field $ R(\kappa) $.

And thus "small" in the sense of cardinality is not well-defined.

That said, the [surreal numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number) come to mind as possibly relevant; while not a field themselves as they are not a set when considered over ZFC, they might be related to the class you're looking for.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question. Small refers not to the size of the class but to containment.

Comment: Actually, the original question just wrote $HSP(K)$ for the smallest variety of algebras containing the class $K$ of algebras. However, I rewrote the question to omit as much universal algebra notation as possible, to make it more accessible. I admit that universal algebra might be a bit more sloppy with respect to sets and classes than category theory, because it's more concerned with other questions and doesn't try to provide an alternative foundation of mathematics.